# Unable to sync project with lean back library

Tags: android-studio

I am using android studio  electric eel . and i am developing android tv app. i  am trying to add lean back  library version 1.1.0 but  file are not importing . i am trying with 1.1.0-rc02 version able to sync with this project but lean back recycle view in not importing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnV1h.png)

I am using android studio  electric eel . and i am developing android tv app. i  am trying to add lean back  library version 1.1.0 but  file are not importing . i am trying with 1.1.0-rc02 version able to sync with this project but lean back recycle view in not importing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)